# How to re-order a mini-panel in a Panel generated page?

Tags: panels, features

I've inherited a site and have been slowly unraveling certain aspects of its construction. Specifically right now, I want to change the order/region a page is loading a mini-panel in a page that I believe is being styled as a Panel due to the css-markup and lack of a template file.

I believe the content type and associated fields and panels were all loaded into the site structure via Features. The general layout of the pieces I want to change right now is like this:

```
    <div class="content__main_wrapper clearfix">
  <div class="panel-panel content__main_sidebar eq-col">
    X
    </div>
  <div class="panel-panel content__main_full eq-col">
    </div>
</div>
```

Where X is what I want to move to the div below, or another div below that so that I can display it on mobile devices below the main content. If I go to look at the admin/structure/mini-panels/list/mini_panel_name/edit/layout no matter how I change the location of the content, it doesn't seem to impact its layout in the nesting of the page overall.

There does not appear to be a Panel Page that is content-type/node% for the content type the panel and mini-panels are attached to or a template doc, so I'm not sure where to look to impact this. Neither are there published blocks associated with these.

I'm not very familiar with the Features module, but it's set to prevent rebuild and revert. Could there be something that's interfering with? Could there be something buried in the imported Features module that's controlling this layout outside of normal theming locations? This also all lives in Pantheon.

Comment: Have you looked to see if you have the correct permissions? I think you need certain permissions to move the content in the layout around. Another thing to consider is that certain panes can be locked. This means they can't be moved from one region to the other. Again, this may be all in the permissions. Another aspect is the features, have you tried turning off the feature to see if that allows you to move the content around?

Comment: @jnpWebDeveloper Appreciate the comment, but I was/am able to override settings, but had been unable to locate the place that setting was being established.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I ended up finding my own answer while working on something else. I realized my scope was wrong, I was looking for an override page referring to a specific page type/section, but what ended up being the case was that there existed an override page for all nodes with unique content/layouts in use for each of them within the same area.

So there was ultimately a Panel Page doing the dirty deed as I had thought, but I was being too specific in where I assumed the changes were made, in part because I assumed an override page would have to maintain the same layout for all pages it overrides, but that's not the case I've learned.